# An error occurred while performing the 'for' loop using Rserve

Tags: java, r

I execute my R code in Rstudio,and it worked well.The following pitcute shows how my R code work.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLZRT.png)

And then,I want to execute my R code using Java through Rserve.The following code is my Java code:

```
c.eval("kandweight=kand(person)");
            c.eval("person");
            c.eval("system=c(3,6,5,9,2)");
            c.eval("systemw=matrix(,length(system))");
            c.eval("k=0");
            c.eval( "for(i in 1:length(system))"
                    + "{"
                    +     "j=sum(system[1:i])"
                    +     "systemw[i]=sum(indexw[1:j])-k"
                    +     "k=sum(systemw[1:i])"
                    + "}");
```

`c`in my Java code is Rserve connection.And I got an error.The error shows that the line`c.eval(    "for(i in 1:length(system))"`eval failed.I am still trying to fix this but need some outside help. Many thanks.

Comment: Hint: have you printed out your string? *You've* put line breaks into the Java source code, but not in the string - so you'll end up with a string including `systemw[i]=sum(indexw[1:j])-kk=sum(systemw[1:i])` which I suspect isn't valid code. Note the `kk` in there. It could be that just adding spaces would be enough... but if not, try adding line breaks in the string instead.

Comment: I'm using Rserve from Go, the workflow that works best is to package the code and just call it, it's just painful to debug otherwise.

Comment: @Aleh a good idea.I will have a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it would become valid if you separate the lines with semicolons, as one would do in R if putting several commands on a single line:

```
c.eval("for(i in 1:length(system))"
                    + "{"
                    +     "j=sum(system[1:i]);"
                    +     "systemw[i]=sum(indexw[1:j])-k;"
                    +     "k=sum(systemw[1:i])"
                    + "}");
```